# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 138562: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, utf-8

I am new to Python and am using Miniconda3 through Anaconda Navigator. I am assisting with a project in grad school where Python is being used to create scientific models. Anyways, I am trying to set up a new desktop to run said models on, yet I am having this error code come up. I am also using sublime text to help read the data sheets. I've tried looking up answers on here and google but to no avail. Would love some help before I break the desktop :)

```
(C:\Users\lc-ms.admin\Python_modeling\miniconda3) C:\Users\lc-ms.admin\Desktop\LANGE OROZCO\python scripts>python e_fmin.py Restricted license - for non-production use only - expires 2022-01-13 Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Users\lc-ms.admin\Desktop\LANGE OROZCO\python scripts\e_fmin.py", line 12, in m = model.from_tsv('C:/Users/lc-ms.admin/Desktop/LANGE OROZCO/python scripts/CMSB_V9.txt') 
File "C:\Users\lc-ms.admin\Desktop\LANGE OROZCO\python scripts\PM.py", line 1108, in from_tsv file = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=sep, index_col=False) #TODO: maybe replace this with the csv reader from the standard library eventually 
File "C:\Users\lc-ms.admin\Python_modeling\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper return func(*args, **kwargs) 
File "C:\Users\lc-ms.admin\Python_modeling\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 586, in read_csv return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds) 
File "C:\Users\lc-ms.admin\Python_modeling\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 482, in _read parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds) 
File "C:\Users\lc-ms.admin\Python_modeling\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 811, in init self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine) 
File "C:\Users\lc-ms.admin\Python_modeling\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1040, in _make_engine return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options) # type: ignore[call-arg] 
File "C:\Users\lc-ms.admin\Python_modeling\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py", line 69, in init self._reader = parsers.TextReader(self.handles.handle, **kwds) 
File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 542, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.cinit 
File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 642, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header 
File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 843, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows 
File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1917, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 138562: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: @thirdsandfourths Please abstain from making cosmetic changes to closed questions. This will just create noise in the system, and deprives the OP of their one chance to fix the _content_ problems.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors